# PHP remove email from list of emails

Tags: php

I'm trying to send emails after a post creation but trying to omit sending email to the creator of the post.

I get `demo3@demo.com, demo2@demo.com, demo4@demo.com` by doing

```
$emails = rtrim($emails,', ');
```

I'm trying to remove `demo3@demo.com`

```
$owners_email = Session::get('user_email'); // which is demo3@demo.com
$emails = rtrim($emails,$owners_email);
```

but I get `demo3@demo.com, demo2@demo.com, demo4`

Comment: use explode function and unset first element

Comment: @mr.void How do you know it'll be the first?

Comment: OP did not wrote. So i saw it from the easiest case.

Comment: @deceze, right, it won't be the first always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$emails = join(', ', array_diff(array_map('trim', explode(',', $emails)), [$owners_email]));
```

In detail, you can do these steps individually if you want:

- `explode(',', $emails)`: turn your email list into an array
- `array_map('trim', ...)`: remove whitespace from the emails
- `array_diff(..., [$owners_email])`: remove the owner's email from the array
- `join(', ', ...)`: collapse the emails back into a list

Answer (score 1):

How about this?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
str_replace($owners_email.",","",$emails);
```

Comment: you need to proceed trailing comma

Comment: You'd have to figure it whether its ,email,    email  or ,email   but str_replace would work